# Running cmd command with Python from specific directory

Tags: python, os.system

When writing a Python code, I could write `os.system('some cmd command')`. How could I make it run from a specific directory (without using a 'cd' command)?

The reason I'm trying to do this is because my cmd command isn't in my cmd PATH, and therefore is recognized only in its own directory.

I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
p = Popen ('file.bat', cwd = 'location')
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

just without having to create a `.bat` file for it...

Comment: Assign the abs path to a variable and pass as an argument? I'm not sure if that's what you're going for.

Comment: Sorry @crownedzero, I didn't really understand your comment. What's an abs path and where should I pass it as an argument to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always do:

```
p = Popen ('../relative/path/to/executable.exe')
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Or you could hard-code an absolute path in there, but be sure to check if the file exists first or to catch any exceptions thrown by the `popen` calls (more pythonic).

LE:
Please note that there is a `cwd` parameter on the `Popen`'s constructor, but the executed program's current directory will be changed to that, it won't look for the executable in there.

Comment: I was going to go for this but I wasn't sure that's what they were trying to do :(

Comment: @Cheshie Yes, sure, there you could write whatever path you want. Not necessarily a bat file, just try it out. LE: I edited the post.

Comment: @Paul, can I write an actual _command_ instead of the exe in your example?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to specify `shell=True` as another argument for the `Popen` constructor. Be sure to read on why that might be a security issue if the command you're running comes from user input in the documentation of the subprocess module.

Comment: Also `shell=True` is needed only if the command is to be passed through the shell, from your original question I understand that your command is an executable script, which shouldn't require that, though this is only an assumption.